# Date Time differences calculation in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a situation where I need to get the differences between two columns.

> Column 1: 01-OCT-13 10:27:15
>   Column 2: 01-OCT-13 10:28:00

I need to get the differences between those above two columns. I tried using '-' operator but the output is not in an expected way.
I need output as follows: 00-00-00 00:00:45

Comment: How can a time be `10:27:60`?  That would be `10:28:00` (60 seconds in a minute).  Are these `DATE` columns (in which case the trailing 60 is not valid)?  Or are they `timestamp` columns (in which case the trailing 60 may be intended to represent fractional seconds and you're just missing the whole number of seconds)?

Comment: Oh sorry...my mistake.. :)

Comment: Columns are of type DATE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query but it is not tested

```
SELECT extract(DAY
               FROM diff) days,
       extract(hour
               FROM diff) hours,
       extract(MINUTE
               FROM diff) minutes,
       extract(SECOND
               FROM diff) seconds,
       extract(YEAR
               FROM diff) years
FROM
  (SELECT (CAST (to_date(t.column1, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss') AS TIMESTAMP) -CAST (to_date(t.column2, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss') AS TIMESTAMP)) diff
   FROM tablename AS t)
```

Comment: But that gets only the seconds difference right..!? What if there is also difference in date as well as hours and minutes?

Comment: Yes its working fine.Can I extract all in one single query?

Comment: Yeah its working thank you so much..If at all I want to find the differences of Month and Year also Shall I follow the same procedure

Comment: @user2037445 I updated query now,check out,delete some comments or lets move to chat

Comment: Yeah even now it is getting the same error

Comment: @user2037445 sorry but I changed conversion type now ,try working or not

Comment: I dont know where I am going wrong,but the same error is repeating.

Answer (score 2):

Try this too,

```
WITH T(DATE1, DATE2) AS
(
SELECT TO_DATE('01-OCT-13 10:27:15', 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),TO_DATE('01-OCT-13 10:28:00', 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL
)
SELECT floor(date2 - date1)
          || ' DAYS '
          || MOD(FLOOR ((date2 - date1) * 24), 24)
          || ' HOURS '
          || MOD (FLOOR ((date2 - date1) * 24 * 60), 60)
          || ' MINUTES '
          || MOD (FLOOR ((date2 - date1) * 24 * 60 * 60), 60)
          || ' SECS ' time_difference

FROM T;
```

Comment: Another method to extract days, hours, minutes and seconds b/w two dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query to find the difference **`seconds`** :

```
select 24*60*60*
(to_date('01-OCT-13 10:28:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')-
to_date('01-OCT-13 10:27:15', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')) diff_secs
from dual;
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/18051)**

Comment: But I need differences between dates as well including days,months,years,hours,minutes,seconds